# What will be the path to import in the source file?

Tags: java

I'm working on a small GUI using Java Swing with Sublime editor and the file structure is as following,

[image]

The GUI is still in the initial shape and looks like the image when I run from the terminal.

```
javac Main.java
java Main
```

[image]

How can I import `EditContainer.java` file in the `Main.java` to use `EditContainer class instance/ object`?

Comment: I am guessing that you can just go to `EditContainer.java` and see its `package` declaration. Then in `main.java` you can simply add `import info.from.that.file.EditContainer;`.

Comment: How can I see the `package` declaration in Sublime ?

Answer (score 3):

Author works in the Sublime text editor, it's not like IDE that provides you the package path. You probably need to set the `CLASSPATH` environmental variable, so your directories become Java packages. Try to set/create environmental variable `CLASSPATH=/path/to/your/project` and then import your file like `import panels.edit.EditContainer`  Try to read here for more info: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot and I will try this out. If works, I will accept your answer then. About SUBLIME, you made a great tool I'm in love with this :)

Comment: No problem, btw it's not me who made the Sublime :) but it's good tool, I'm agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to import `panels.edit.EditContainer` but in order to know for sure, open the EditContainer.java file and look for a line that starts with package.

You should import that package + .EditContainer

Comment: `import panels.edit.EditContainer;` and `import edit.EditContainer;`  doesn't work. I don't have any line in the file that starts with package. I'm coding in Sublime and adding all the files by hand.

Comment: can you provide the line that starts with package in EditContainer?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but, there is no such line. I'm coding in sublime and adding all the files by hand. The project structure is provided in the image above.